# C++ Importing a DLL and using its callback funtions

Tags: c++, dll

I have imported a DLL into my program, and there are a few functions as follows:

```
typedef int (*FEEDQ_CALLBACK)           ( long nSD, long nQtype,  long nNumber ) ;
typedef int (*CALLDISP_CALLBACK)        ( AODFeedDispositionBase* CallDisposition );
typedef int (*SERVICE_STATUS_CALLBACK)  ( long nSD, long nStatus ) ;
typedef int (*AUTH_SERVICE_CALLBACK)    ( long nSD, char* sSDesc, long nSType ) ;
typedef int (*INBOUND_ABANDON_CALLBACK) ( long nSD, DCCProInboundDisposition* inbounCall ) ;
typedef int (*SESSION_STATUS_CALLBACK)  ( long lTypeId, long lStatus ) ;

extern "C"
{
    //Methods
    AODFEEDAPI short Initialize(const char * sTenantName, const char * sUserID, const char * sPassword, AUTH_SERVICE_CALLBACK pAuthSrvFunc, SERVICE_STATUS_CALLBACK pSrvStatFunc, FEEDQ_CALLBACK pFeedQFunc, CALLDISP_CALLBACK pCallDispFunc, INBOUND_ABANDON_CALLBACK pInboundCallFunc, SESSION_STATUS_CALLBACK pSessionStatFunc = 0);
    AODFEEDAPI short Close();   
    AODFEEDAPI short StopService( long nServiceID, long nQueueAction );
    AODFEEDAPI short StartService(long nServiceID);
}
```

I want to call the `Initialize()` function in the DLL. I'm confused as to how I should pass the parameters in the callback function.

Comment: An example would be really nice :)

Comment: What does "pass the parameters in callback function" mean? Do you know what a callback function is?

Comment: If you could please explain me :) How it works

Comment: i want to call the Initialize method in my cpp file

Comment: Then call it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass parameters to the callbacks. The callbacks are functions you define in your own code and then give to the DLL so it can call them when needed, passing parameters to you. For example:

```
int MyFeedQCallback( long nSD, long nQtype, long nNumber )
{
    // do something... 
} 

int MyCallDispCallback( AODFeedDispositionBase* CallDisposition )
{
    // do something... 
}

int MyServiceStatusCallback( long nSD, long nStatus )
{
    // do something... 
}

int MyAuthServiceCallback( long nSD, char* sSDesc, long nSType )
{
    // do something... 
}

int MyInboundAbandonCallback( long nSD, DCCProInboundDisposition* inbounCall )
{
    // do something... 
}

int MySessionStatusCallback( long lTypeId, long lStatus )
{
    // do something... 
}

int main()
{
    ...
    short ret = Initialize("tenant name", "user ID", "password", &AuthServiceCallback, &MyServiceStatusCallback, &MyFeedQCallback, &MyCallDispCallback, &MyInboundAbandonCallback, &MySessionStatusCallback);
    ...
    long serviceID = ...;
    StartService(serviceID);
    ...
    StopService(serviceID, queueAction);
    ...
    Close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this and see :)

Comment: Hey @Remi i got this DLL without any guide on how to implement. Could you further tell me how to call the methods you created in the example. Should those methods be called before the 'Initialize' method? Would much appreciate if you could explain it to me on how to pass values into the methods, Sorry for the trouble cause i don't know C++  :)

Comment: @VidathAdheesha **YOU** don't call them, the **DLL** calls them